# How to set default values for a object in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

My terraform snippet:

```
variable "machine_details" {
  type = object({
    name              = string
    size = string
    username               = string
    password = string
  })

  default = [
    {
      name              = "example-vm"
      size = "Standard_F2"
      username               = "adminuser"
      password = "Notallowed1!"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting error as below.

```
    Error: Invalid default value for variable
    │
    │   on variables.tf line 38, in variable "machine_details":
    │   38:   default = [
    │   39:     {
    │   40:       name              = "example-vm"
    │   41:       size = "Standard_F2"
    │   42:       username               = "adminuser"
    │   43:       password = "Notallowed1!"
    │   44:     }
    │   45:   ]
This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: object required.
```

I tried map(string) but didn't work too.

similary list(string) also.

I am trying the latest azurerm provider.

Also, in the gcp, we have option to provide count(for instances), so if I provide 2, two instances will be created.

How to do the same with azure and aws?

How to resolve this?

Comment: Why is the default value a list?

Comment: Because we want to keep all the data related to the azure instance resource in a single place.

Comment: That is not what I meant: you specify the type to be an object but you provide a list as default, those two types do not match up. Either the type needs to be list(object(...)) or the default must not be a list.

Comment: Can you share a sample code on how to pass the values here

Comment: Well, he did, just enclose the object with `list()`.

Comment: If you came here by google to find out how to set defaults for some entries in the object, the solution is to mark them optional: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/defaults

Answer (score 14):

it is working this way.

```
variable "machine_details" {
  type = object({
    name = string
    size = string
    username = string
    password = string
  })

  default = {
      name = "example-vm"
      size = "Standard_F2"
      username  = "adminuser"
      password = "Notallowed1!"
    }
  
}
```

And can refer like this : var.machine_details.name

Answer (score 3):

***As `Marko E` and `luk2302` have mentioned , You have to declare and pass the variable as below :***

```
variable "machine_details" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    size = string
    username = string
    password = string
  }))

  default = [
    {
      name = "example-vm"
      size = "Standard_F2"
      username = "adminuser"
      password = "Notallowed1!"
    },
    {
      name = "example2-vm"
      size = "Standard_F2"
      username = "adminuser1"
      password = "Notallowed2!"
    }
  ]
}
```

***So that if you want to use `count` then you can use something like below :***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "ansumantest"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  count = length(var.machine_details)
  name                = "aks-nfs-public-ip${count.index}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  count = length(var.machine_details)
  name                = "example-nic-${count.index}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    public_ip_address_id = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.example.*.id, count.index)}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_ssh_public_key" "example" {
  name                = "ansuman-sshkey"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  public_key          = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  count = length(var.machine_details)
  name                = var.machine_details[count.index].name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = var.machine_details[count.index].size
  admin_username      = var.machine_details[count.index].username
  admin_password      = var.machine_details[count.index].password
  disable_password_authentication = true
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.example.*.id, count.index)}"]

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = var.machine_details[count.index].username
    public_key = azurerm_ssh_public_key.example.public_key
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Terraform 1.3.0, this can be done using the optional function.
I changed your example to demonstrate some more functionalities

```
variable machine_details {
  description = "Example using optional values"
  type        = object({
    id        = string
    name      = optional(string,"defalt_name") 
    size      = optional(number, 500)
    username  = optional(string,"defalt_username")
    password  = optional(string)
  })
}
```

Creating an object id is mandatory, password is null by default

```
machine_details = {
  id  = "id-example-1"
}
```

result

```
 { 
  id  = "id-example-1",
  username ="defalt_name",
  size = 500,
  username ="defalt_username",
  password = null
}
```

Creating object overriding default username and setting password

```
machine_details = {
  id  = "id-example-2",
  username ="my_name",
  password = "secret" 
}
```

result

```
 { 
  id  = "id-example-1",
  name ="defalt_name",
  size = 500,
  username ="my_name",
  password = "secret" 
}
```

see also [Optional with defaults](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/request-for-feedback-optional-object-type-attributes-with-defaults-in-v1-3-alpha/40550?page=2)